# Strange connectivity of Windows Server 2016 VMware VM

Tags: virtual-machine, connection, vmware-workstation, windows-server-2016

I am running a Windows Server 2016 Desktop Experience VM on VMware Workstation 14. I was not getting any connectivity, and tried several configuration changes to fix it. Eventually, I noticed that the default gateway in the Virtual Network Editor NAT settings didn't match the ipconfig info on the host, so I changed that.

Now, I can ping addresses out on the internet, but I cannot browse. I am having DNS issues (I cannot ping www.google.com) but I also can't browse by IP addresses, so I don't think DNS is my browsing issue.

Additionally, the connectivity icon in the bottom right has the yellow warning triangle and says no connection, but then when I ping out to the internet it works, and then the yellow triangle goes away for around 30-45 seconds before coming back.

I am a student running this VM as a test system. So there's no real environment, and I'm happy to try whatever might work with no concern of consequences. If any more info would help solve the problem, please let me know.

Comment: The gateway in the NAT shouldn't be the same as the host's gateway address.  Your host should get a xxx.xxx.xxx.1 IP , the gateway is usually xxx.xxx.xxx.2, and your VMs should be in the xxx.xxx.xxx.128-254 range. Try adding a new NAT network and assign that to your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no "real environment" the simplest solution would probably be to set the network adapter to bridged. This way the VM would appear like a normal host with its own IP on the network.

To do this go into the VMs settings page and in the hardware tab select the network adapter. On the right handside you can now change the corresponding setting.